# Entity Framework Core One-to-One, Not Unique

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Given two tables, TrackingTag and TrackingTagStatusUpdate:

```
public class TrackingTag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class TrackingTagStatusUpdate
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int TrackingTagID { get; set; }
    public TrackingTag TrackingTag { get; set; }

    public int Epoch { get; set; } //32-bit

    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string APConnectedSSID { get; set; }
}
```

As there will be many TrackingTagStatusUpdates, I want to add a field "LatestStatusUpdate" to TrackingTag, for performance reasons.

```
public class TrackingTag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? LatestStatusUpdateID { get; set; }
    public TrackingTagStatusUpdate LatestStatusUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

`LatestStatusUpdate` is optional, as it may not be set if there are not yet any Status Updates for the Tag.

Entity Framework Core complains that "The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'TrackingTag.LatestStatusUpdate' and 'TrackingTagStatusUpdate.TrackingTag'.". I then add

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TrackingTag>().HasOne(x => x.LatestStatusUpdate).WithOne(x => x.TrackingTag).HasForeignKey<TrackingTagStatusUpdate>(x => x.TrackingTagID);
```

to `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`, however this results in Entity Framework Core creating a relationship with a Unique constraint, which will not work as there will be many TrackingTagStatusUpdate with the same TrackingTagID.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: `public class Tracking Tag { public HashSet<TrackingTagStatusUpdate> TrackingTagStatusUpdates { get; set; } = new(); public TrackingTagStatusUpdate LatestStatusUpdate { get; set; } }`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have worked:

```
public class TrackingTag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(LatestStatusUpdate))]
    public int? LatestStatusUpdateID { get; set; }
    public TrackingTagStatusUpdate LatestStatusUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure how to achieve the same with the Fluent API though.

Comment: Your FK should be defined from the TrackingTag side since multiple Statuses will be assigned to a single TrackingTagId. 
`modelBuilder.Entity<TrackingTag>().HasOne(x => x.LatestStatusUpdate).WithOne(x => x.TrackingTag).HasForeignKey<TrakingTag>(x => x.LastStatusUpdateID);`